# Long running Django task with text updates

Tags: python, django, celery, task-queue

With a Django web app what would be the easiest way of having a long running task run in the background but be able to provide the user with progress updates in text and percentage done/ETA?

I've looked at Celery and I couldn't see a way to do regular text updates, only a progress update with percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- user submits data
- start a celery job with the data
- the celery job posts text updates to a database
- the django web app queries the database periodically and displays the text update to the user

Comment: Ended up using websockets with redis :)